# Strikethrough text when checkbox checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Can anyone help me with this code so that when the checkbox is checked, the text has a strikethrough as well?

I can get either the strikethrough to work, or the css styling, but I cannot get both to work at the same time :(

I've tried to combine the code below with the code in the link, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
[CSS checkbox strikethrough Demo](https://codepen.io/KMSkelton/pen/OMVovK)

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this simply using pseudo elements `::before` and `::after` with `text-decoration: line-through`

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  display: none
}
/* Create a custom checkbox - using ::before */
.checkmark::before {
  content: "";
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input~.checkmark::before {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked~.checkmark::before {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

/* strike throught the text */
.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<label class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Two</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have both the checkbox and the text *inside* the label (contrary to the example you are referencing where the label comes *after* the checkbox) you will have to rearrange your markup slightly.

The text you want to modify has to come after the checkbox for the sibling selectors to work (`+` or `~`), and (as CSS cannot select parent elements) the text has to be inside its own element.

I suggest you put it inside its own `span` named `.text`:

```
<label class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  <span class="text">Two</span>
</label>
```

You can then select the text when it is the sibling of a checked checkbox using the following:

```
.container input:checked ~ .text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Putting this into your code we get the following:

```css
/* This is our new part*/

.container input:checked ~ .text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
  <span class="text">Two</span>
</label>
```

Comment: @dippas As long as OP placed both the checkbox and the text inside the same element it's actually needed, isn't it?

Answer (score -3):

So first create a label that text inside you want to cross, add it after checkbox and add this to css:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked  + label{
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked  + label{
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<label class="container">
  <input type="checkbox"><label> Cross me </label>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```